# bash cannot find .profile when run bash command from directories other than the $home directory

Tags: python, bash, shell

In my /home/user directory, clearly there is a .profile file. Within this directory, I can run bash command, e.g. `$bash run.sh`. But in any other directories, when input `$bash`, it always complains

```
bash: .profile: No such file or directory
```

PS.: I need to run `$bash` in non-root directory, because I actually have a python script run.py which contains this line `subprocess.call( ['bash', 'test.sh'], shell=True)`. When running this python script, bash complains no .profile.

Does anybody know why? Thanks for help!

Comment: What is in the `run.sh`?  Is it trying to source `.profile` directly or something?

Comment: are you running the python script under root user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution and let me know if it works--as I do not have access to your script and/or file structure, and this issue is the only one I can see in the available information, I will present this as a possible answer:

This may result from splitting your input when using the `shell=True` argument. According the docs, you must use the command as such:

```
subprocess.call('bash test.sh', shell=True)
```

because executing through a shell does not require sanitized input, even though this is a security hazard.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Your proposed script  worked:
subprocess.call('bash test.sh', shell=True)
I also notice that my original script works too if I get rid of shell=True:But why couldn't I split the inputs?

Comment: @leoking87 I'm glad it worked! If you found the solution was helpful, please mark it as correct for future programmers. The reason you can't split the input (I believe) is because bash parses spaces differently from the way Python does. Without `shell=True`, python needs to know where each part of the command begins and ends before it can splice it together and execute. But when you tell it to just use bash, which is much better at reading its own input, the commands do not have to be santized--bash is good at reading its own input.

Comment: @leoking87 For example, without the `shell=True` command, you would not have to include backslashes to help bash parsing spaces. Python is good at doing that. If you included `shell=True` and forced the command to be executed without being spliced together by Python, you would have to do the original bash command, including backslashes. You can try this for yourself by using backslashes when `shell=True` is included and then removing them when not using `shell=True`.